# Can "as matter of fact" be used to express a contradictory opinion?

Tags: phrases, expression-choice, contradiction

I'm aware you can do that with *actually*:

> **actually** 
>   ...used when expressing a contradictory or unexpected opinion or
>   correcting someone. "‘Tom's happy anyway.’ ‘He isn't, actually, not
>   any more.’"

*Source: [Google](https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=define%20actually&oq=define%20actually&gs_l=serp.3..0i7i30l3j0l2j0i30j0i8i30.127788.128734.0.128912.7.6.0.0.0.1.159.393.0j3.3.0.msedr...0...1c.1.64.serp..5.2.269.nmhHirzn5hs).*

Can I do the same with *as matter of fact*?

Example:

> I looked at the sky and searched for constellations.
>
> **Matter of fact**, I wasn't an expert. My knowledge was limited to
>   horoscope columns and astronomy documentaries.

Comment: Yep, it sure can.

Comment: The sense is correct. In written form, though, I think it better to complete the expression: "As a matter of fact..." instead of just "Matter of fact," which sounds more informal or conversational.

Comment: It functions in much the same way as "Truth to tell, ..." or "To be honest..." The implication is that what follows will cast new light on something previously described from a different perspective or with a different attitude.

Comment: Note: _as matter of fact_ is not correct. It's _as **a** matter of fact_ or just _matter of fact_, colloquially.

Answer (score 2):

As Dan Bron and others point out in comment from more than a year ago, "as a matter of fact" certainly can introduce a contrasting or contradictory statement—although it can also serve to introduce further support for a statement or position already expressed.

By way of demonstrating the use of "as a matter of fact" to introduce a contradictory view, I offer four examples drawn from a Google Books search for the phrase "as a matter of fact the opposite." From C.J. Mellin, "[Articulated Compound Locomotives](https://books.google.com/books?id=3H3EjDBtg7gC&pg=PA27&dq=%22As+a+matter+of+fact+the+opposite%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi55Y7EhIPPAhVFKGMKHcSHA54Q6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q=%22As%20a%20matter%20of%20fact%20the%20opposite%22&f=false)" (December 1908):

> It should also be remarked that, due to absence of jerks and slack in starting, as well as the more uniform cylinder pressure, the stresses on the machinery and framework are considerably reduced; and, further, that the milder exhaust produces a less intense heat and a better utilization of it, all of which contribute to a reduction in the repairs of the locomotive as a whole, compared with a simple engine, if it ere practical to construct one of this type. This has never been advanced as a feature to the credit of the articulated engine because it is difficult to give it any definite value; but is referred to as a reply to the often repeated supposition that these engines are hard to keep in repair. **As a matter of fact** the opposite is the case because on account of the subdivision of the work in two engines the parts are lighter and easier to handle in repairs and renewals.

From Tom Kraeuter, [*Keys to Becoming an Effective Worship Leader*](https://books.google.com/books?id=qazBTowTZ6oC&pg=PA101&dq=%22As+a+matter+of+fact+the+opposite%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi55Y7EhIPPAhVFKGMKHcSHA54Q6AEIMzAE#v=onepage&q=%22As%20a%20matter%20of%20fact%20the%20opposite%22&f=false) (991):

> Beyond heart preparation is the physical preparation. It is amazing to me how rampant the lack of preparation is within the charismatic movement. The church overall associates being spontaneous with being led by the Holy Spirit. Planning or preparation is usually associated with being in the flesh or, at least, not being led by the Spirit. Nowhere dos the Bible teach this. **As a matter of fact** the opposite is true. God Himself had a plan for salvation since before time began. It was not a last minute, spontaneous thought; it was carefully planned out.

From Federico Etro, [*Competition, Innovation, and Antitrust: A Theory of Market Leaders and Its Policy Implications*](https://books.google.com/books?id=aSV7DEA_ch8C&pg=PA194&dq=%22As+a+matter+of+fact+the+opposite%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi55Y7EhIPPAhVFKGMKHcSHA54Q6AEIPzAG#v=onepage&q=%22As%20a%20matter%20of%20fact%20the%20opposite%22&f=false) (2007):

> Unfortunately, whether the incentives to invest are efficient or not is more an empirical question that a theoretical one, and we still do not see a consistent piece of evidence showing that current patent systems provide excessive incentives in a systematic way, or that we should totally eliminate IPRs legalizing "intellectual expropriation"—as Boldrin and Levine (2005) actually suggest. **As a matter of fact**, the opposite may be true. Recently, Denicolò (2007) analyzed a general model of the organization of innovations and obtained a simple rule for the optimal level of patent protection: his empirical estimates suggest that current patent systems do not over-compensate innovators, while they may actually induce too limited incentives to invest in R&D.

And from Joop Stolk, ‎Theo Boer & ‎Ruth Seldenrijk, [*Meaningful Care: A Multidisciplinary Approach to the Meaning of Care for People with Mental Retardation*](https://books.google.com/books?id=_PIkBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA32&dq=%22As+a+matter+of+fact+the+opposite%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi55Y7EhIPPAhVFKGMKHcSHA54Q6AEILjAD#v=onepage&q=%22As%20a%20matter%20of%20fact%20the%20opposite%22&f=false) (2013):

> In the words of three of these parents, there exists no tension between their vision on the purpose of life and how they value the life of their child. **As a matter of fact**, the opposite is true for the parents of Art. Their child is privileged over others, because "he will be able to enter heaven freely."